# Find unique polynomial of deg $d$ s.t $(P(0), P(\frac{1}{d}), P(\frac{2}{d}), \ldots,P(1)) = a\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $T:\mathcal{P}_d(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of polynomials of degree max $d$ and with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

We define the linear map$$ T:\mathcal{P}_d(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^{d+1} $$
$$P \mapsto (P(0), P(\frac{1}{d}), P(\frac{2}{d}), \ldots,P(1)) $$

I want to show that there exists a unique polynomial $P$ such that $T(P) = (a_0,\ldots , a_i)$ for any $(a_0,\ldots , a_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$

I.e $P(\frac{i}{d}) = a_i$

I tried to take general polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$ and solve for the coefficients of the general polynomial

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{d} \lambda_ix^i, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for } i = 0,\ldots, d$$

But I can't seem to figure out the pattern.

It it clear (?) that $a_0= \lambda_1 \text{ and } a_d =  \sum_{i=0}^{d} \lambda_i$ but what about $a_1,\ldots, a_{d-1} $ ?

Sorry for the minimal effort shown here but I find this problem quite challenging.

Comment: The set of polynomials with degree less than or equal to $d$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ is usually denoted by $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq d}$

Comment: @vrugtehagel Yeah, sorry about that. My lecturer seems to prefer $\mathcal{P}_d(K)$, where $K$ is a field, for some unknown reason and I just copied the problem.

Comment: Ah, right. As you noticed, this problem is closely related to linear algebra. You have a set of $d+1$ equations with $d+1$ unknowns - is your question to prove that such system has one unique solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show, that the map is bijective. It is a linear map of finite-dimensional vector-spaces of the same dimension. Hence it suffices to show that kernel is trivial. However the kernel consists of polynomials of degree $d$ with at least $d+1$ zeros...

Comment: That did it! I was looking at the problem at a weird angle. got it Thank you so much!